# Undefine class method and back to define it later

Tags: ruby

I need to disable a class method for some time, then enable it again. How could I do that? I know that I can remove a method:

```
class Foo
  def Foo.bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end

Foo.bar    # => bar

class <<Foo
  remove_method :bar
end

Foo.bar    # => undefined method `bar' for Foo:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Now I need `Foo.bar` again. How could I do that? I tried to save the method in a proc

```
m = Proc.new { Foo.bar }
```

and then define it again:

```
class Foo
  define_method(:bar, &m)
end
```

but I get

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'm' for...
```

So I flattened the scope

```
P = Class.new(Foo) do
  define_method(:bar, &m)
end
```

but I get undefined method if I run it

```
P.bar
Foo.bar
```

Is it possible to save a method, undefine it, and then define it back?

Comment: I think that if you describe what you want to implement you'll receive better and more helpful answers. Try not to focus on your implementation, give us the general idea and the requested functionality. The answer could be much more elegant and simple.

Comment: Note : `define_method` creates instance method, not a singleton method for a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of keeping a method body in a proc, you should keep methods as methods. Constantly keep it defined under some different name, and switch `Foo.bar` between alias of it or not.

```
class Foo
  def Foo.temporal_bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end

Foo.singleton_class.class_eval{alias bar temporal_bar}
Foo.bar # => bar

Foo.singleton_class.class_eval{remove_method bar}
Foo.bar # => Undefined local variable or method `bar' for #<Class:Foo>

Foo.singleton_class.class_eval{alias bar temporal_bar}
Foo.bar # => bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out `instance_eval`:

```
(class << Foo; self; end).instance_eval do
   define_method(:bar, &m)
end
```